# Maximize $\binom{N-m}{n-k}/\binom{N}{n}$ with respect to $N$

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, binomial-coefficients, nonlinear-optimization

The question is actually in the title. I wish to maximize this function with respect to $N$, where $m, n$ and $k$ are fixed naturals less than $N$ and also $k\le \min(m,n)$. How do I go about proving it?

**My attempt**
I am having problem since this is not an analytic function (since I don't want a large scale approximation, I don't want to use Stirling's formula), otherwise I would have differentiated with respect to $N$ to solve this. Also, if I expand the binomial coefficients on the numerator and denominator, the number of terms above are $n-k$, whereas there are $n$ terms below. How should I go about proving it?

Comment: Find the ratio between $f(N)$ and $f(N+1)$

Comment: @Empy, I get $\dfrac{f(N+1)}{f(N)}=\dfrac{(N-m+1)(N-n+1)}{(N-m-n+k+1)(N+1)}$, but how does that help?

Comment: If the ratio is more than 1, then $f$  is increasing, if the ratio is less than 1 then $f$ is decreasing, so find where the ratio equals 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $N$ be the integer for which the maximum is achieved, then we must have

$\frac{N -1-m \choose n-k}{N-1 \choose n} \leq \frac{N-m \choose n-k}{N \choose n} \geq \frac{N +1-m \choose n-k}{N+1 \choose n}$

- $\frac{N -1-m \choose n-k}{N-1 \choose n} \leq \frac{N-m \choose n-k}{N \choose n}$

$\Rightarrow N \leq \frac{mn}{k}$

- $\frac{N +1-m \choose n-k}{N+1 \choose n} \leq \frac{N-m \choose n-k}{N \choose n}$

$\Rightarrow N \geq \frac{mn}{k}-1$

Combining the above two inequalities, we have,

$\frac{mn}{k}\geq N \geq \frac{mn}{k}-1$

$\Rightarrow N=\lfloor \frac{mn}{k} \rfloor$